# Getting raw data using Scapy

Tags: python, wireshark, scapy, pcap

I'm trying to achieve the "Follow TCP\UDP Stream" of Wireshark - using scapy. Meaning I only want the raw data, and not all of the other attributes of the tcp\udp packet.

When I just do:

```
pcap = rdpcap('dummy.pcap')
hexdump(pcap[0])
```

I get the entire packet, meaning the source, destination etc.

Let's say I got a DNS request which looks like:

```
0000   52 54 00 12 35 02 08 00  27 78 07 78 08 00 45 00   RT..5...'x.x..E.
0010   00 3E 00 40 00 00 80 11  1E 51 0A 00 02 0F 08 08   .>.@.....Q......
0020   08 08 04 01 00 35 00 2A  41 83 31 1E 01 00 00 01   .....5.*A.1.....
0030   00 00 00 00 00 00 04 74  69 6D 65 07 77 69 6E 64   .......time.wind
0040   6F 77 73 03 63 6F 6D 00  00 01 00 01               ows.com.....
```

I would like to get only:

```
00000000  31 1e 01 00 00 01 00 00  00 00 00 00 04 74 69 6d 1....... .....tim
00000010  65 07 77 69 6e 64 6f 77  73 03 63 6f 6d 00 00 01 e.window s.com...
00000020  00 01
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
pkt = pcap[0]
hexdump(pkt[DNS])
```

This will work because you can use any of the Scapy layers to index a given packet, so to get just the DNS part of an Ethernet/IP/UDP/DNS packet you just need `pkt[DNS]`.